# Where should unit tests be placed in a CI/CD pipeline for a dotnet app?

Tags: .net, unit-testing, devops, cicd

We are planning to add some unit tests for our apps in our CI/CD pipeline, and since we are using dotnet6.0 and based on Microsoft documentation, "dotnet test" command both builds and tests the application, shouldn't we put the test stage before the build stage( in which we build and containerize the app)?

Comment: Test is usually after build. First you check if build is success, if not, then no point in proceeding and testing. If success, then run tests.

Comment: There is no *one solution* and you should put your tests, where it bests fit. But at least they should happen somewhere *after* build, cause for testing it is also needed, that your sources are build.

Comment: Thanks, the other question is the tests should be run on which branch? what is the best practices in here? should we run those tests on the main branch or development?

Comment: You should run tests on any pipeline where you want to STOP delivery when the tests fail or where you want to be informed of failed tests. Typically, that would involve both main and develop branches, but if your project setup dictates "error in code should lead to a dead runtime environment", your workflow may differ.

Answer (score 0):

You can add the `--no-build` flag to `dotnet test` to prevent it from building before testing. You obviously have to have done a `dotnet build` before or the tests won't be able to run.

You can read about it in the [dotnet test documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-test).